# view the table definition using the SQLSERVER management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What does the output of "Script Table As -> CREATE To" mean ? I have a partitioned table, but when I right click on it in the Management Studio and choose "Script Table As -> CREATE To", the output didn't contain anything related to table partition. I was expected to find the "ON partition_scheme_name", but it didn't show up.

```
USE [FcstDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StFcst]    Script Date: 2014-06-10 15:54:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StFcst](
[MID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[INITDATE] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[FH] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[STID] [char](5) NOT NULL,
[WW03] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WW06] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WW12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[T] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[TMAX12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[TMIN12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[PR03] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[PR06] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[PR12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[PR24] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[RH] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[CLOUD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[VV] [int] NOT NULL,
[SLP] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_T] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_TMAX12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_TMIN12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_PR03] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_PR06] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_PR12] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_PR24] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_WD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[E_WS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StFcst] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[INITDATE] DESC,
[FH] ASC,
[MID] ASC,
[STID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

`Script Table As -> CREATE To` creates script containing `Create command` of given table structure without any kind of data.

Do you intend to copy the data somewhere else? If yes, consider using [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) command.

For Create Partition scheme please visit [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179854.aspx).

Script table documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169684%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Comment: any official documentation?